# specifying favicon in a type-safe manner in yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod

this is a re-post of my original question that I asked on the yesod mailing list (please see http://groups.google.com/group/yesodweb/browse_thread/thread/934c4141fc615cb) in an attempt to get a faster response.

I am trying to figure out whether it is possible to generate a `<link>` with the `type` attribute that corresponds to the MIME type sent by the HTTP handler that serves the favicon file.

so far I have this link:

`<link rel="icon" href=@{FaviconR} sizes="32x32" type="image/png">`

and this handler:

`getFaviconR :: Handler ()
getFaviconR = sendFile "image/png" "config/favicon.png"`

I am looking for a way to make sure that the code compiles only if `getFaviconR` and `<link>` have the same MIME type.

I realize of course that I can omit `type` attribute from the link altogether and rely on the client to figure out the type, but think of it as a theoretical question.

I am new to Haskell, so may be I am asking for something impossible. no?

Comment: Not very familiar with Yesod. Is it possible to write something like `<link rel="icon" @{Favicon} sizes="32x32">` and have the template for `Favicon` generate both the `href="foo"` and `type="image/png"` bits? Then at least both `"image/png"` bits are in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do here is to define the image type in a separate variable and use it in both places.